# load flat file with timestamp using IICS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica, flat-file, informatica-cloud

I need to load a Flat file to a snowflake table. flat file comes in daily with timestamp. how can I do this in IICS.

Comment: What specific issue are you facing implementing this task?

Comment: how do I load it? If Indirect file is the only option, how do i create txt file for using as Indirect file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do an indirect file load and have a batch/shell script that generates the file list and is run as a command in your source object

Comment: Thank you, I did a shell script to generate the file list. but when the file doesnt exist teh script doesnt generate any file... this way informatica will process the old file. I want it to generate file, but a blank one. can you guide how to do this?

Comment: it is working.. Thank you so much